# Identify device between iPad ios13 and MAC OS in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Project**: ASP.NET c#.

In my project, we have different pages for mobile devices.

So when any request first come it will go to first page and in page_load event.

From that event we have code to identify device weather it is mobile or desktop. But from last few days it has issue with iPad iOS13 because it has same user agent as mac os .

So it is not identifying the iPad device.

Please help me to identify device whether it is iPad or Mac OS.

Thanks.

Comment: You can refer to this tutorial here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b696c4/display-mode-provider-in-mvc-5-application/

Comment: My project is created in webform .